# Edit iptables in red-hat Linux 6 without root user privilege

Tags: linux, redhat

what are the possible ways to Edit iptables in red-hat Linux 6 without root user privilege   ? 
We can edit or modify iptables only as root user. How can we perform edit operation without root user privilege in redhat linux 6 Enterprise.

Comment: I dont think you can.   If you can get root access then you can setuid the iptables command to make it so it runs with root access when called by anormal user. (Without need to sudo or su)

Comment: Bit of info on setuid here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-bsd-linux-setuid-file/

Comment: Can you explain @james sefton that process. I means Complete Description of your above suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Login as root and run:

chmod u+s /path/to/iptables/command

You should now be able to run iptables command without being root.

Be aware that this means *all* users can now run iptables command as root.

Comment: Ok, how can I just allow setuid only for users belong to a group

Comment: I don't know if that can be done.  Setuid is a flag to tell the system to execute the file as its owner.  You could possibly remove the world execute permission from the file and set the group of the iptables file.  (chmod o-x /path/to/iptables , then chown root:somegroup /path/to/iptables)